# Is it possible to recreate the history from stellar-core?

Tags: stellar-core

We have a private stellar network and for some reason the archive is corrupt and a new node cannot get the history. Is there a way to recreate the full archive from stellar-core?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately archives *are* the canonical history -- there's no other place to replay history from. They're what you would be replaying history *from* if you wanted to replay it.

Are you sure the archive is actually corrupt, rather than the new client merely being misconfigured? What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: It seems that the archive is actually corrupt. ie data is missing from the archive. The archive was set to be on tmp folder unfortunately.

The new node is starting to ingest the data from archive but it is stooping after 10-15 mins saying cannot find the next ledger on the archive.

Comment: Unfortunately if the archives are corrupt there's nowhere else to recover data from. It's like trying to recover a backup when your backup drive is corrupt -- that _was_ the backup.